# When searching ABAddressBook, how do I search for contact names while excluding job titles?

Tags: iphone, ios, abaddressbook

When I search the `ABAddressBook` for names of contacts, it returns matches that include job titles.

For example, let's say I've got a contact named John Smith, and he's a Technology Analyst.

If I search for `ABAddressBook` entries for names that `contain[cd]` `Te`, I would like to avoid seeing John's name, since Te is not a substring of "John Smith".

How do I search the `ABAddressBook` for a name while excluding a job title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your predicate to filter the array of records should be something like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
      @"record.name contains[cd] %@", string];
```

Make sure that `record.name` only contains the elements identified by

```
const ABPropertyID kABPersonFirstNameProperty;
const ABPropertyID kABPersonLastNameProperty;
const ABPropertyID kABPersonMiddleNameProperty;
```

and not

```
const ABPropertyID kABPersonJobTitleProperty;
```

Comment: I know it's been a while but how do you get record from the ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople array? All I can get is __NSCFType

Comment: Something like `ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, i );`

Comment: Thanks for this. Would you mind posting a snippet? I've tried this: NSMutableArray *records = (__bridge NSMutableArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople( addressBook );
    
    NSPredicate * myPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"record.phoneNumber contains %@",@"123"];
    
    try {
            [records filterUsingPredicate:myPredicate];
    }
    catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"%@",exception);
    }
    {}