# Autocompleting contacts textfield

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a textfield where the user can write a phone number but I want the user to be able to start writing a name of one of his' contacts (of the address book) and the textfield should give him an autocomplete for possible results while he's typing.
The app already has permission to the address book when the user starts writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the example of autocomplete email search. So please modify it is according to you..And i Hope it will help you.

https://github.com/DharmbirChoudhary/AutoCompleteSearchInTextField

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using a TableView (for showing autocomplete results) and NSPredicate have a look on this link for more details

[When searching ABAddressBook, how do I search for contact names while excluding job titles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541645/when-searching-abaddressbook-how-do-i-search-for-contact-names-while-excluding)

Answer (score 1):

I used [this](https://github.com/hoteltonight/HTAutocompleteTextField) library in my project for autocomplete.